# seo url rewriting

Tags: php, .htaccess, seo

I have write url Rewriting in htaccess file

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/subject/([^/]+)/$ subjectlist.php?dept_id=$1
```

but is not work i write as other link in htaccess file

```
RewriteRule ^subjects/$ subject.php,RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$  chapter.php?course=$2
```

please help

Comment: ignore rewriting urls for SEO, it's mostly garbage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try write rules line-by-line

```
RewriteRule ^subjects/$ subject.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$  chapter.php?course=$2
```

Comment: i write line-by-line as RewriteRule ^subjects/$ subject.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$  chapter.php?course=$2
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/subject/([^/]+)/$ subjectlist.php?dept_id=$1  but last url is not work.